# How would one go about extending the click area of material input to its container?

Tags: input, angular-material

We've noticed many users attempting to click the area just outside the actual input.  Since there's no click listener on the `mdInputContainer`, nothing happens and the users assume they can't type in the input :-(  I've come up with a way to extend the click area to the entire `mdInputContainer` but wished I could've used a better approach like maybe decorating the existing directive or something like that.  **How would one go about extending the click area of the `input` to the `mdInputContainer`?**

Here's what I did that works but seems wrong:

```
.directive('mdInputContainer', mdInputContainer);

function mdInputContainer() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'mdInputContainer',
        link: link
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function link(scope, element, attrs, mdInputContainerCtrl) {
        element.on('click', function () {
            mdInputContainerCtrl.delegateClick();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't changing the css be the best option?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd go about triggering all of the input's click behavior by simply changing the css on the container.  Can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean to just add a padding on the input

Comment: oh ok, well padding isn't really the issue.  Have you seen the material inputs?  Here's a demo just in case:  https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input  These are just very different from what most users are comfortable with (unfortuantely because they are really beautiful IMHO)

Comment: Oh I see! I've never used angular so I'm no much help, but if your code above is functional, it seems short enough and easy to explain that I feel like you did find a good solution to your problem. I wouldn't worry about it, especially with a comment explaining why that code is there.